# What does the "index" line mean with git diff --no-index?

Tags: git-diff

I have the impression that arbitrary files on disk can be compared with:

```
git diff --no-index path1 path2
```

But the output includes an "index" line with what looks like commit references.  For example

`cd /tmp; git diff --no-index /etc/passwd /etc/group` produces

```
diff --git a/etc/passwd b/etc/group
index 8d8e802..ab0d13c 100644
--- a/etc/passwd
+++ b/etc/group
@@ -1,55 +1,89 @@
-root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
-daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
...
```

What does the "8d8e802..ab0d13c" mean or refer to?